# Bluebird: Get reference to original function that was promisified

Tags: promise, bluebird

After doing `promisify` on a specific function with bluebird - is it possible to get a reference to the original function that was promisified?

Why: I'm using a helper that gets argument names from the function and on promisified functions it gives back `(_arg0, _arg1, _arg2)`, I was hoping it was possible to get the original function signature from somewhere.

Comment: This may help ... The name of a promisified version of a function gets the suffix "Async". Strip that off and you are back to the original name. From inside any function, the function itself is `arguments.callee` and its name is `arguments.callee.name`.

Comment: Why not just save the original function into its own variable before promisifying? If you showed us the context here for the overall problem, we might have more options.  Or, you could attach the original as a property of the promisified one.

Comment: Your code should never rely on a function signatures or even parameter names in the code anyway. What exactly are you doing with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can work around it though.

If it is promisified with `promisifyAll` you can access it without the `Async` suffix - otherwise, you'd have to do it yourself:

```
var promisified = Promise.promisify(cbFunction);
promisified.original = cbFunction;

// access as promisified.cbFunction from that point on.
```

Otherwise, the original function is captured via a closure and you can't reliably access it. In all honesty you probably shouldn't since that'd meddle with minification anyway.

Comment: +1 for *probably shouldn't*                                                                           :-)

Comment: Thanks, all these manual ways don't really work for me (I only have the function reference), I was hoping bluebird was saving the original somewhere. When you say I shouldn't - is it only because of minification? Or are there other reasons that would also apply on the backend?

Comment: @Madd0g mainly minification. If you want bluebird to use a reference use promisifyAll.